# Angularfire 'Firebase' is not defined

Tags: angularjs, firebase, yeoman, angularfire

I am trying to setup firebase, angularfire for my Yeoman, AngularJS Application. I followed this tutorial here (https://www.firebase.com/tutorial/#tutorial/angular/0), however, I keep getting a

```
"app/scripts/controllers/main.js 
    line 32 col 23 'Firebase' is not defined."
```

How do I get past this?

Here is my main.js

```
.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', '$firebase', '$filter', function($scope, $firebase, $filter) {
    var ref = new Firebase('FIREBASE_URL');    // <--- line 32
    $scope.campaigns = $firebase(ref).$asArray();
```

and here are the two lines of scripts I added to get firebase and angularfire into my app. I changed the version of angularfire from 0.8.0 to 0.7.0 because of ([Firebase, AngularFire Error: Module firebase is not available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25021003/firebase-angularfire-error-module-firebase-is-not-available)). I also have these two lines right underneath by bower_conponents scripts in my index.js for reference.

```
<script src='https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/1.0.15/firebase.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdn.firebase.com/libs/angularfire/0.7.0/angularfire.min.js'></script>
```

I believe it is still version compatibility issue but I am not sure.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Firebase, AngularFire Error: Module firebase is not available](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25021003/firebase-angularfire-error-module-firebase-is-not-available)

Comment: I actually posted that one as well. That was the first error I was getting and this post is the error I got after the 'Error:module firebase is not available'. I thought it would be best to separate the two as they are two different questions. I linked the two posts because they are closely related, however in my opinion, still different.

Comment: I had a similar issue and in my case it turned out that `.$asArray()` is not available in earlier versions than 0.8.0

Comment: @Ionbausch I'm not sure if that is the problem because it is complaing about the line above `.$asArray()` and also I tried removing `.$asArray()` but it still gives the same error.

Comment: $asArray is not available in 0.7.0. Regardless of why Firebase is undefined (probably because of a syntax error caused by .$asArray)

Comment: Yea the problem was the compatibility of versions. I realized then that the `Firebase is undefined` notice within my `grunt serve` was not the issue. More detail here https://github.com/firebase/generator-angularfire/issues/21

Answer (score 0):

Firebase is probably undefined because of this syntax error: `.$asArray`

But, regardless, `$asArray` is not available in AngularFire 0.7.0.