# Super basic Firebase error, "Firebase is not defined"

Tags: firebase

I'm making the move into Firebase. But Day One I'm stumped with a simple one liner.

This is right from the demo:

var myDataRef = new Firebase('https://un2ubl6u7zs.firebaseio-demo.com/');

And returns in my Chrome Console:

[image]

This is from the demo link, but I get exactly the same response in the console for any firebase DB I create. It's probably something REALLY simple, just trying to wrap my brain around Firebase, it's very different coming from a decade in the SQL world.

Thanks for pointers. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will only have access to Firebase, if you include the Firebase JavaScript client as a script:

```
<script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/2.4.0/firebase.js"></script>
```

This will make the `Firebase` object (and may others) available to your script.

I recommend that you start with this [5-minute interactive tutorial for Firebase](https://www.firebase.com/tutorial). Adding the script tag is explain in step 1 there.

There was a similar question yesterday: 
[Uncaught ReferenceError: Firebase is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34968284/uncaught-referenceerror-firebase-is-not-defined)

Comment: The 5-minute interactive tutorial is no longer available at the Url provided. Is this still available? Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

This will not work with the new client.

see upgrade guide: https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/firebase-web

[image]