# React Web App renders blank when in production

Tags: reactjs, github-pages, firebase-hosting

I finished developing a professional portfolio website for myself (since I will be graduating this May). Everything looked great when I was using the development server. However, after I tried to deploy it to GitHub Pages, only a blank screen shows. The site should be reachable at https://shaynajrosado.github.io/Portfolio.

After getting frustrated, I tried seeing whether hosting it on Firebase would make a difference.

[Click here to see Firebase-Hosted Project](https://professionalportfolio-6a357.web.app/)

Still, nothing shows up.

[This links to a picture of the error message I get when I right-click on the blank page & Inspect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zjRxQ.png)

After clicking the error message, it takes me to the React website which translates the error message into: "e(...): Nothing was returned from render. This usually means a return statement is missing. Or, to render nothing, return null."

However, in my code, there really aren't any return statements missing. Below is a link to the project repository:

https://github.com/shaynajrosado/Portfolio/tree/gh-pages

I currently have the project set to use branch gh-pages as the source.

Any words of advice would be very greatly appreciated as I continue to wrestle with this!

Comment: You did not include the firebase script in the html, see information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38800727/1641941).

Comment: I actually would like to avoid using Firebase if I could use GitHub pages...and on GitHub pages it says it's nothing is being returned. I removed all firebase scripts and re-pushed the code

Comment: Actually your first link works for me. Keep in mind that with gh pages, it takes a little bit of time for changes to be applied to production (like 5 min sometimes).